# Checking if words in a text file exist in a second text file TOO SLOW

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a text file and I'm trying to find out if all the words in that text file exist in the lexicon or "dictionary". If there's a word that's not in the dictionary, the output should be the word and how many times it occurs.

The code works fine on small size text files, but not on large ones. Can't tell if it crashes or if its still working.

I'm using Python 3

```
import os
import argparse
from collections import Counter


def countoov(lexicon,text):
    lexicon_list = []
    oov = []
    word_list = []
    with open(lexicon,"r",encoding="utf-8") as lf:
        lines = lf.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        line = line.strip()
        lexicon_list.append(line)
    #print(lexicon_list)
    #import pdb; pdb.set_trace()            
    
    with open(text,"r",encoding="utf-8") as tf:
        lines = tf.readlines()    
    for line in lines:
        line = line.strip().split()
        word_list.extend(line)
        #count = 0
        #Problem here
        #for word in line:
        #    if word not in lexicon_list:
        #        oov.append(word)
    for word in word_list:
        if word not in lexicon_list:
            oov.append(word)
    
    counter = Counter(oov)

    return counter

if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('--textfile', type=str, required=True, help='input directory of train text')
    parser.add_argument('--lexicon',type=str, required=True, help='input directory of lexicon')
    args = parser.parse_args()

    print(countoov(args.lexicon, args.textfile))
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Note that when working with really large files you don't want to read it all at once. This would fill up your ram and possibly slow down your computer or crash your program. If that's the case you should consider reading one line at a time.

Comment: Another tip: use list comprehension to remove some excess for loops and variable assignments (which might slow down the program). Try this: `lexicon_list = [line.strip() for line in lf.readlines()]`  inside the first `with`

Comment: By the way -- if your input files are sorted ahead-of-time, you can do this as an O(n+m) operation in constant memory with the same algorithm the standard UNIX `comm` tool uses. (Personally, I'd just use `comm` -- dict files usually _are_ pre-sorted, after all)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is tidied up version of the main function, which:

- uses a set for the lexicon (for a large lexicon, it will be much faster than a list for inclusion testing)
- avoids storing any other large collections in memory, apart from the counts themselves (note the use of `yield` to make a generator that the counter can iterate over)

```
def gen_oov(lexicon,text):
    lexicon_set = set()
    with open(lexicon,"r",encoding="utf-8") as lf:
        for line in lf:
            lexicon_set.add(line.strip())

    with open(text,"r",encoding="utf-8") as tf:
        for line in tf:
            for word in line.strip().split():
                if word not in lexicon_set:
                    yield word

def countoov(lexicon, text):
    return Counter(gen_oov(lexicon, text))
```

Comment: Thanks for all the answers and explanation I appreciate it! It works much faster now.

Answer (score 2):

1. Your lexicon should be in a `set`, not a `list`, so that you can check for word presence in constant-time instead of linear.
2. You can just build up your missing-counter directly while reading the file instead of loading the whole thing into memory and making a temporary list of missing words.

Thus:

```
def count_missing(lexicon, text):
    words = set()
    with open(lexicon) as lf:
        for line in lf:  # Assuming one word per line in the lexicon
            words.add(line.strip())
    missing = Counter()
    with open(text) as tf:
        for line in tf:
            for word in line.split():
                if word not in words:
                    missing[word] += 1
    return missing
```

Comment: Very interesting use of a counter - like a kind of `defaultdict`. Never realised that you could do that.

Comment: @alani `Counter` is basically `defaultdict(int)` with some handy helper methods on top.

Comment: Thanks, handy to know. I realised that it was a subclass of `dict`, but didn't realise that it was a `defaultdict`. (Makes obvious sense though.)

Comment: @alani The semantics are slightly different, iirc `Counter` won't automatically add something if you check for it whereas a `defaultdict` will actually create an entry with a `0` value. There may be other minor differences.

Comment: @tzaman could you help me with a similar problem? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63834766/text-normalizer-on-large-text-files-too-slow-python

Comment: @alani could you help me with a similar problem?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63834766/text-normalizer-on-large-text-files-too-slow-python